# JavaScript Calculate what exact date it would be after exactly X Years

Tags: javascript, date

Javascript- How to get an **exact date** after exactly 'X' years from a given date (birth date), say 'YYYY/MM/DD'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to calculate age from date, here is the code you need:

```
    var birthDate = getDateFromTextbox();
    var today = new Date();
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
        age--;
    }
```

If you want calculate year from 2 dates, replace

```
var today = new Date();
```

by

```
var today = yourDate();
```

If you want add year to Date try it:

```
date.setYear(date.getFullYear + 7);
```

Comment: No.. I have the solution you just gave me. Thanks..... I need to get the DATE if I have one date and add some years to it.... For example what is the exact date from 12-12-2015 after 7 years

Comment: I had edit answer. Using date.setYear(date.getFullYear + 7); to edit year. But not try with date have day which is 29/02

Answer (score 0):

A trivial version would be

```
function addYearsToDate(date, years) {
    return +date.slice(0, 4)+years + date.slice(4);
}
```

Here, the `+date.slice(0,4)` makes a number out of the first four characters of the date, to which we add the number of years, then concatenate that with the remainder of the input date.

```
> addYearsToDate('1953/04/18', 62)
< "2015/04/18"
```

You will need to special-case Feb. 29.

This assumes you want the input and output in string form YYYY/MM/DD. For more sophisticated date manipulation, consider using a library like moment which would allow you to do things like

```
moment('1953/04/18').add(62, 'years')
```